# Acessing a map in another viewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, mkmapview, uitabbar

I have an application that uses a UITabBar when my app loads VC1 loads (ViewController number 1) but I have a button in this precise viewcontroller that needs a map that is in VC2 but if the user never clicked the second button on the tabBar VC2 was never loaded and therefore The map isn't even there!
i tried to use[(VC2 *) [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewDidLoad] but VC2.mapView is still nil after that. Any Idea how can I get to that mapview in that situation?

Comment: This seems more like a design problem that a purely technical one. What is VC1 actually trying to do to the map?

Comment: I believe it is irrelevant but I need to take a printscreen of that map so I need the information to be loaded into it and printscreen it... I know that I could create on out of the VC1 view frame and there do what I have to do with it but that would make me have to implement some MK protocols to load the data into that new map and I would like to avoid it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the controller array reference is correct, you should be able to force a view to load using code in VC1 like:

```
UIView *vc2MainView = [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] view];
```

At that point the view and subviews for VC2 should be initialized and your references should be valid.

Comment: O don't know if I got it right but you're saying that by creating a pointer to the view it will be forced to load?

Comment: From the documentation of the view property in UIViewController class reference: "If you access this property and its value is currently nil, the view controller automatically calls the loadView method and returns the resulting view."

Comment: Well I'm not sure it will solve my problem since I tried to use the viewDidLoad myself and the mapview Was still nil. I'll test it as soon as I can. Thank you very much.

Comment: viewDidLoad is called **after** the loading; it doesn't cause it.